# How to troubleshoot an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am writing a game of sticks that will hopefully play against me. The idea is detailed in [this HTML document](http://nifty.stanford.edu/2014/laaksonen-vihavainen-game-of-sticks/handout.html) but basically I have code that should create a very rudimentary type of AI that will adaptively learn the optimal way to play.

I have code for Player 1 and for the AI, but the issue is I need the AI to run continuously until I tell it to stop. I tried encasing all of my code in a `while True:` but I think something in my conditionals is causing the code to stop rather than continuously looping back around. I was hoping someone might have a suggestion for how I can implement a workaround.

```
import random
import sys

"Global Variables"
prompt = '>>> ' 
btw_1_3 = 'Please pick a number beteween 1 and 3.'


#Introduction to the game
raw_input("Welcome to the game of sticks! Press <Enter> to continue...")
print("How many sticks are there on the table initially (10-100)?")
num_sticks = int(raw_input(prompt))
print("Ok, there are %s sticks on the board.") % (num_sticks)
print("|")*num_sticks

#Initialize a dictionary that we will change
stick_dict={}
for number in range(1,num_sticks+1):
    stick_dict["hat{0}".format(number)]=[[1,2,3]]



while True:
    while num_sticks!=0:

        #player 1
        while True:
            print "Player 1: How many sticks do you take (1-3)?"
            player_1 =  int(raw_input(prompt))

            if 1 <= player_1 <= 3:
                break
            else:
                print (btw_1_3)

        num_sticks = num_sticks - player_1

        if num_sticks == 1:
            print("Ok, there is %s stick on the board.") % (num_sticks)
            print("|")*num_sticks

        elif num_sticks < 1:
            print("Player 1, you lose.")

            #If Player 1 loses, then the AI wins and we want to execute this 
            for key in stick_dict:
                if len(stick_dict[key]) == 2:
                    stick_dict[key][0].append(stick_dict[key][1])
                    del stick_dict[key][1]
                    sys.exit()

        else:
            print("Ok, there are %s sticks on the board.") % (num_sticks)
            print("|")*num_sticks




        #AI player
        guess = random.choice(stick_dict["hat{0}".format(num_sticks)][0])
        if guess > 1:
            print "The computer chose %s sticks" % (guess)
        elif guess == 1:
            print "The computer chose %s stick" % (guess)


        stick_dict["hat{0}".format(num_sticks)].append(guess)
        print stick_dict

        num_sticks = num_sticks - guess


        if num_sticks == 1:
            print("Ok, there is %s stick on the board.") % (num_sticks)
            print("|")*num_sticks

        elif num_sticks < 1:
            print("Player 2 (AI BOT), you lose.")
            #If the AI loses
            for key in stick_dict:
                if len(stick_dict[key]) == 2:
                    del stick_dict[key][1]
            break
        else:
            print("Ok, there are %s sticks on the board.") % (num_sticks)
            print("|")*num_sticks
```

For reference, when I run the code posted above it stopped iterating after Player 2 lost and I had to "KeyboardInterrupt" rather than having the code loop back around and keep playing until I decide to quit.

```
Welcome to the game of sticks! Press <Enter> to continue...
How many sticks are there on the table initially (10-100)?
>>> 10
Ok, there are 10 sticks on the board.
||||||||||
Player 1: How many sticks do you take (1-3)?
>>> 3
Ok, there are 7 sticks on the board.
|||||||
The computer chose 3 sticks
{'hat9': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat8': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat1': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat3': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat2': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat5': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat4': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat7': [[1, 2, 3], 3], 'hat6': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat10': [[1, 2, 3]]}
Ok, there are 4 sticks on the board.
||||
Player 1: How many sticks do you take (1-3)?
>>> 3
Ok, there is 1 stick on the board.
|
The computer chose 1 stick
{'hat9': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat8': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat1': [[1, 2, 3], 1], 'hat3': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat2': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat5': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat4': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat7': [[1, 2, 3], 3], 'hat6': [[1, 2, 3]], 'hat10': [[1, 2, 3]]}
Player 2 (AI BOT), you lose.

^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/andrewthappa/Documents/python/scripts/sticks/human_v_ai.py in <module>()
     29 
     30 
---> 31 while True:
     32         while num_sticks!=0:
     33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    num_sticks = 10
    while num_sticks!=0:
        ...
```

you need to reset the counter

Comment: While `num_sticks` didn't need to be reset where you pointed, you were right that it needed to be reset. When either Player 1 or the AI lost, that was where `num_sticks` should have been reset. In any event, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, say I wanted to run the loop just 100 times. I've tried incrementing a counter and then setting the outer most `while` loop to `while count < 100` but the loop continues well after the counter is past 100. Do you happen to have any suggestions for how to do that?